# How does a Hypervisor distinguish multiple VMs running on it and isolate them from the underlying h/w?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, xen, hypervisor

How does a Hypervisor distinguish multiple VMs running on it and isolate them from the underlying h/w?
e.g. if there is a system call from with in a guest OS, how does the HV know it belongs to a specific guest OS?
Not much details about lower details of HV operation.

Comment: Hypervisor doesn’t know anything about syscalls. It works on a lower level since its whole point is to make the guest not know any difference from running on bare metal. In the usual case.

Comment: Thanks Sami. So you mean HV does not really know for which VM it is processing the trap. It simply processes it? Sorry I have no background in how an OS works...

Answer (score 2):

A normal system call in a guest is processed by the guest OS without intervention of the hypervisor.

However, when the guest *does* cause a trap to the hypervisor (not a system call, but some other operation that requires hypervisor service), the hypervisor knows which guest it is because it knows which guest it scheduled on that CPU.